# Why does this return the same index?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to run two different lua string find on the same string `" (55)"`

Pattern 1 `"[^%w_](%d+)"`, should match any number

Pattern 2 `"[%(|%)|%%|%+|%=|%-|%{%|%}|%,|%:|%*|%^]"`, should match any of these `( ) % + = - { } , : * ^` characters.

Both of these patterns return 2, why? Also if I run a string match, they return `(` and `55` respectivly (as expected).

Comment: I've never used Lua, but you say [^%w_](%d+) should match any number, but would it not match any non alphanumeric or underscore '(' and then match any number? So '(55' would be a match?

Comment: Your second pattern only matches `(` and `)`. With the first one, you are trying to match a non-word char and capture 1+ digits - maybe you want to use a frontier pattern, `"%f[%w_]%d+"`?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the patterns with [`string.find`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) that finds *the first occurrence of the pattern in the string passed. If an instance of the pattern is found a pair of values representing the start and end of the string is returned. If the pattern cannot be found `nil` is returned.*

**Both patterns find a match at Position 2**: `[^%w_](%d+)` finds `(` because it is matched with `[^%w_]` (a char other than letter, digit or `_`), and `[%(|%)|%%|%+|%=|%-|%{%|%}|%,|%:|%*|%^]` matches the `(` because it is part of the character set.

However, the first pattern can be re-written using a *frontier* pattern, `%f[%w_]%d+`, that will match 1+ digits if not preceded with letters, digits or underscore, and the second pattern does not require such heavy escaping, `[()%%+={},:*^-]` is enough (only `%` needs escaping here, as the `-` is placed at the end of the character set and is thus treated as a literal hyphen).

See this [Lua demo](http://ideone.com/S44oLW):

```
a = " (55)"
for word in string.gmatch(a, "%f[%w_]%d+") do print(word) end
-- 55
for word in string.gmatch(a, "[()%%+={},:*^-]+") do print(word) end
-- (, )
```